# Merge [cloud-foundry-bosh] into [cf-bosh]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

The [cloud-foundry-bosh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cloud-foundry-bosh) tag has only 17 questions, and its [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/cloud-foundry-bosh/info) explicitly says, "This tag is a duplicate of [cf-bosh](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/cf-bosh/info)." The [cf-bosh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cf-bosh) tag, on the other hand, has 82 questions (still not a lot but almost 5 times as many, and there will probably be even more as I continue retagging [bosh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bosh) questions as [cf-bosh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cf-bosh) where appropriate) and actual relevant information about [BOSH](https://bosh.io) in the [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/cf-bosh/info). I propose that [cloud-foundry-bosh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cloud-foundry-bosh) be made a synonym of [cf-bosh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cf-bosh).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I merged [cf-bosh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cf-bosh) and [cloud-froundry-bosh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cloud-froundry-bosh), as they were the same, and also added a synonym: [cf-bosh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cf-bosh) ← [cloud-froundry-bosh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cloud-froundry-bosh).

As for [bosh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bosh), the issue is that it has the same name as the cloudfoundry product. Something that can take care of this is to rename the tag from [bosh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bosh) to some other more meaningful and unambiguous name.

Given that the Wikipedia page on BOSH mentions it as BOSH Protocol, I renamed the tag as [bosh-protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bosh-protocol), which probably should be solve some problems with the users tagging their questions incorrectly.